# localeLocationPattern not find in angular dynamic location

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

i doo translate with angular-translate and localization with angular dynamic localization. I try this code, but localization not changed. I think that problem is that angular can not find localeLocationPattern. Here is code

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider, tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {


$translateProvider.translations('en', {
LANGUAGE: 'Language',
LOG_OUT: 'Log out',
LOG_IN: 'Log in',

 });

 $translateProvider.translations('hr', {
LANGUAGE: 'Jezik',
LOG_OUT: 'Odjava',
LOG_IN: 'Prijava',

BUTTON_LANG_HR: 'Hrvatski',
BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'English'
  });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
    $translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true);
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();


    //i think that angular can not find thistmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.8/angular-locale_aa-dj.min.js'); 
    console.log(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider);
});
```

in controller i add this

```
app.controller('klupeController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$translate', 'tmhDynamicLocale', '$locale', '$http', 
function ($rootScope, $scope, $translate, tmhDynamicLocale, $locale, $http)      {
 $locale, 'tmhDynamicLocale'
 $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
    };
    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function (event, data) {
        // asking angular-dynamic-locale to load and apply proper AngularJS $locale setting
        tmhDynamicLocale.set(data.language);
        console.log(data.language);
   });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this. My solution is here. I delete completly

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function (event, data) {
    // asking angular-dynamic-locale to load and apply proper AngularJS $locale setting
    tmhDynamicLocale.set(data.language);
    console.log(data.language);
 });
```

And set path in tmhDynamicLocale.js only. After this, set $cookieStore, like this

```
tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.useStorage('$cookieStore');
```

And, nowits working, but when i switch language, localization is stil not change, i need refresh page to see change. For this i set in my ctrl, where is function to change language and localization, function for page refresh like this

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);   
    };
    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function (event, data) {
        // asking angular-dynamic-locale to load and apply proper AngularJS $locale setting
        tmhDynamicLocale.set(data.language);
         $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});  //for page refresh
    });
```